# How to create if(...) to understand what is language in the text of String? android app

Tags: java, android

I want to create an `if` statement in order to understand to which language a String refers.

For example, for this statement `String = "Neka";` the language `en` and for
`String = "Нека";`, the corresponding language is `ru`.

Comment: What are you after? You have dictonaries of words in all languages? Are you looking for character sets? And, what have you tried?

Comment: i have no idea,  dictonaries of words in all languages i cannot create and use because my app user all natinations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an online [Language Detection API](https://detectlanguage.com)

Create your key.

And use request using http.

```
URL : http://ws.detectlanguage.com/0.2/detect?q=yourstring&key=yourapikey
```

You get a response.

```
{
   "data":{
      "detections":[
         {
            "isReliable":false,
            "confidence":0.45171339563862928,
            "language":"es"
         },
         {
            "isReliable":false,
            "confidence":0.083565459610027856,
            "language":"pt"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in an offline solution, there are several java libraries which are useful to detect languages. For example

- [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/1.5/detection.html#Language_Detection)
- [detectlanguage-java](https://github.com/detectlanguage/detectlanguage-java)

Try those libraries.